# Enabling parent form ignores disabling child FormControl in valueChanges

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have two checkboxes, where one is only enabled if the other is checked.

To implement this behavior, I use `valueChanges` on the first checkbox and disable/enable the second checkbox appropriately.

Now lets say I disable the form until I do some async work - perhaps fetching from an API that fills the form with values in some cases. When I re-enable the form, the valueChanges callback is executed, but the call to `disable()` is ignored, and the second checkbox is still enabled.

Do I need to extract the logic for disabling the form controls and run it every time I enable/disable the parent form, or am I missing something?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kw9htm?file=src/main.ts

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line:

```
this.testForm.controls.testParent.valueChanges
  .pipe(startWith(this.testForm.controls.testParent.value))
  .subscribe((val) => {
    if (val) {
      this.testForm.controls.testChild.enable();
    } else {
      // this.testForm.controls.testChild.setValue(false); // REMOVE THIS LINE
      this.testForm.controls.testChild.disable({ onlySelf: true });
    }
  });
```

You are hardcoding the value, reactive forms made this changes for you.

in my opinión you should split form and functionality like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `

    <input type="checkbox" (change)="disableForm()">

    <form [formGroup]="testForm">
      <input formControlName="testChild" type="checkbox">
    </form>

  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  isEnableForm: boolean = true;
  testForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.testForm = formBuilder.group({
      testChild: [false],
    });
  }

  disableForm() {
    this.isEnableForm = !this.isEnableForm;
    this.isEnableForm
      ? this.testForm.controls.testChild.disable({ onlySelf: true })
      : this.testForm.controls.testChild.enable();
  }

}
```

Comment: Check the updated stackblitz, both checkboxes are still enabled with `setValue` removed.

Comment: @StephenPanzer ... is fixed now ?? it seem that it is woking fine...